# How to remove background color between lines on h1 tag?

Tags: html, css

so here is the picture how I need it to look -
http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg339/scaled.php?server=339&filename=capture2dn.jpg&res=medium
And here is the picture, how I currently have -
http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg526/scaled.php?server=526&filename=capturegdq.jpg&res=medium
Well bascially, I need to remove the background: color-code; between the lines. Is there anything I could do, so it would remove the background color for h1 between lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
​<h1>
<span>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </span>
​</h1>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​h1{
    width:200px;
}
h1 span
{
    background-color:red;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mcd9F/

---

Using `line-height` will increase the gap:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mcd9F/1/

Comment: Wow, did I said you are Genius? If no then, here you go - "You are Genius!" Will accepta s soon, as I will be able to accept answer ;)! Thanks!

Comment: The question is to remove the colour , y u aswered with adding a colur ?

Comment: @AkhilThayyil - I have removed the colour from the whole `h1`, by applying it to the `span`. See my fiddle.

Comment: @Curt Great answer. Is there a way to control the padding within middle lines of the `span`? It's kind of hard to explain, but maybe my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcd9F/36/) will help demonstrate. So if the text spans 3 lines, I can add padding to the beginning of the first line and the end of the last line with `padding` in the CSS for the `span`. But the middle line's text hugs the background color. Can I somehow get there to be padding on the middle line like the first and last?

Comment: @praguian Hi I see what you are referring to, and I think you would be better off creating a new question which refers to this question. That way others may be able to provide a solution too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @Curt Thanks, I [asked a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757561/padding-middle-lines-of-a-span).