# Padding middle lines of a span

Tags: html, css

This is a follow-up to the Q&A found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327766/how-to-remove-background-color-between-lines-on-h1-tag/9327807#comment13943906_9327807).

Is there a way to control the padding within middle lines of the span? It's kind of hard to explain, but maybe my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mcd9F/39/) will help demonstrate. So if the text spans 3 lines, I can add padding to the beginning of the first line and the end of the last line with padding in the CSS for the span. But the middle line's text hugs the background color.

Can I somehow get there to be padding on the middle line(s) like the first and last?

The goal is a look similar to this:

[image]

```
<h1>
<span>I can pad the beginning of the first line and end of the last line, but middle lines hug the edge!</span>
</h1>
```

```
h1{
    width:350px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 span
{
    background-color: #5577aa;
    color: #fff;
    line-height:32px;
    padding: 5px 25px 5px 35px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't arbitrarily add border-radius or padding to word-wraps because the HTML element doesn't actually end there. If you want what you have in the diagram you will need to use three elements.

Comment: I figured as much, thanks. So it seems like there should be a way via javascript to dynamically allocate the right number of words to each span at least, right? So the overall piece can still be dynamic according to the inputted text?

Comment: You could measure the height of the span and based on the font's line-height, calculate the number of lines used, then break them into separate elements.